# Align C preprocessor definitions

Tags: alignment

How do I align C preprocessor definitions using vim's [Align plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align)?

Something like:

```
#define ORING 'r'
#define OLRING "ring"
```

where the string `'r'` should be aligned with `"ring"`.

I don't find any example like this at http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/align.html#Examples they all use a separator like `=`.

I have tried `:Align \tsp` which might work because it aligns on whitespaces, but nothing happens.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you simply insert a space before `'r'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:<range>Align \s` which will use the white spaces as separators. It will give you the following:

```
#define   ORING    'r'
#define   OLRING   "ring"
```

To align only the part between the quotes you can use: `:<range>Align \('\|"\).*` which means *"align starting on `'` or `"` and all characters following it"*. This gives the following:

```
#define ORING  'r'     
#define OLRING "ring"
```